# cannot cast from list<map<string, object>> to list<map<string, string>>

Tags: spring

I'm stuck and need some assistance.  The code below works fine with Springframework v2.5.6, but get that error when using any version greater.

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getAclUserRoles(String akoId) {
    List<Map<String, String>> roles = null;
    if (null == akoId || "".equals(akoId.trim())) {
        return null;
    }
    Object[] params = { akoId };
    roles = (List<Map<String, String>>) getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(ACL_QUERY, params);
    return roles;
}
```

I understand the cast error, but it's strange how it works under that version but not future, and can't find anything in the documentation that gives any details.

Comment: Which version are you currently testing against?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the return type changed between v2.5.6 and more current releases.

`Map<String, object>` can not be cast to `Map<String, String>` due to how [covariance and contravariance work in Java](https://briangordon.github.io/2014/09/covariance-and-contravariance.html).

Comment: How can I setup getJdbcTemplate().queryForList to retrieve string versus Object?  I'm trying to fix code that is several years old, and bringing spring up to standard.

Comment: You could change it to use this version of the method, specifying Map<String,String> as your class: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, had to replace with this line:

List> roles =  (List) getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(ACL_QUERY, params);